# How can I access to an iframe DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I just want to access to the DOM in an iframe.
I can display in the Chrome console to the whole iframe definition with the code below :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var toto = window.parent.$("#compare_package")[0];
console.log(toto);
});
```

But I don't find the solution to access to the '#document' content.
I tried :

```
var toto = window.parent.$("#compare_package")[0].contentDocument;
```

or :

```
var toto = window.parent.$("#compare_package")[0].contentWindow;
```

But it does not work.
Does anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: does iframe has same origin as your page? (protocol, port and domain)

Comment: `$('document')` is invalid use `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

it only works in same origin policy

```
// you iframe
<iframe id="some" src=""></iframe>

// bind after iframe content is loaded
$("#some").contents().find('.item');
```